# How to get breadcrumbs in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, navigation

The navigation toolbar on nautilus always shows an editable text version of the current folder. How do I get it to show clickable breadcrumbs?

I am running nautilus 3.4.2 on ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

Open a Terminal and run:
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry false`
If you want to use the editable location bar temporarily,you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.To return back to breadcrumbs just press <kbd>esc</kbd>.

Comment: I wish it was that simple but no, that did not work.

Comment: Then open a Terminal and run `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry false`

Comment: I tried doing that using gconf-editor, but that didn't work. But your solution did, thanks! :)

Comment: Gnome3 replaced GConf with DConf/GSettings. Use `dconf-editor` (package `dconf-tools`) instead of `gconf-editor`